# Why is /signin-oidc returning 404 after using Azure AD sign-in?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, http-status-code-404, azure-web-app-service

I'm implementing Azure AD authentication in an ASP.NET Core MVC 3.0 app. I have followed the instructions in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) tutorial, the option 2; the only difference is I used an existing app instead of the downloadable example (I made sure of installing all NuGet packages and adding configuration data as provided by the tutorial and the example). I'm testing this app in my local machine.

App is properly registered in Azure so I have a client ID and a tenant ID. Data as follows:

- Redirect URIs: Web, `https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc`; Web, `https://localhost:5002` (in that order)
- Logout URL: `https://localhost:5002/signout-oidc`
- Implicit grant: **ID tokens**

Trying to access an action marked with `[Authorize]` triggers the sign in process, but when it's complete, it redirects to `https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc` and then the site returns 404.

`appsettings.json` config:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[OMITTED]",
    "TenantId": "[OMITTED]",
    "ClientId": "[OMITTED]",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Startup class:

```cpp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace TestApp.WebSite
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services
                .AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority += "/v2.0/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; 
            });

            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
            services
                .AddControllersWithViews(options => options.Filters.Add(GetAuthorizeFilter()))
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(GetLocalizationOptions());
            app.UseStaticFiles(GetStaticFileOptions());
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        private RequestLocalizationOptions GetLocalizationOptions()
        {
            var cookie_request_culture_provider = new CookieRequestCultureProvider
            {
                CookieName = "UserCulture"
            };
            var providers = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
            {
                cookie_request_culture_provider,
                new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider()
            };
            var supported_cultures = new CultureInfo[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("es")
            };
            var result = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                RequestCultureProviders = providers,
                SupportedCultures = supported_cultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supported_cultures,
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en")
            };
            return result;
        }

        private StaticFileOptions GetStaticFileOptions()
        {
            var result = new StaticFileOptions
            {
                ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
                DefaultContentType = "text/plain"
            };
            return result;
        }

        private AuthorizeFilter GetAuthorizeFilter()
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            var result = new AuthorizeFilter(policy);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice that can point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the part of your code that has the redirect URI set?

Comment: How do I check that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because you miss the `app.UseAuthentication();` so that OIDC middleware can't handle the authentication process in your application :

```
app.UseAuthentication(); //add this line 
app.UseAuthorization();
```